# Submit app with development provisioning profile on app store

Tags: ios, app-store, ipa, provisioning-profile

I have just submitted an app to the app store and it get submitted and is live but now i realized that i created ipa with Ad-Hoc provisioning profile(it is 100% sure). But app on appstore cant be submit without distribution profile. How is it possible????

Comment: Your question is confusing!!! or am I missing something?

Comment: We accidentally submitted an App Update with the AdHoc Distribution Profile (the one we use for HockeyApp QA builds), rather then the App Store Profile. That was a few versions ago...  And, it apparently worked fine, so we stuck with it.  The benefit for us is, we can actually smoke test what is uploaded to Apple...  I'm sure, at some point that will break, but I feel a lot better being able to smoke test what is actually submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can not submit app without making distribution profile.

-first make the Distribution profile.
-in code signing select the distribution profile
-archive your project.
-select the submit app to the apple store.
-write your itunesconnect username and password
-and distribute.